# Why is the differential of magnetic induction (dB) equal to zero?

Tags: electromagnetism

I deduced this conclusion from the differential form of magnetic flux. Because d(phi)=B*dS
(1) This formula is the same in almost all physics textbooks. However, according to the definition of magnetic flux, phi=B*S, fully differentiate both sides of this formula, d(phi)=dB*S+B*dS
(2). Comparing with (1) and (2), we can get dB=0. But why? Looks very unreasonable.

Comment: because we assume that there is no significant change in magnetic field for a differential area $=ds$, hence $dB=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magnetic flux is defined over a differential area element as:

$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$ d$\phi$ = $\vec{B}$ . $\vec{dS}$

If $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{dS}$ are parallel, this reduces to:

$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$d$\phi$ = B dS $\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$

For a finite area the magnetic flux will be:

$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\phi$ = $\int {d\phi}$ = $\int{\vec{B} . \vec{dS}}$

If $\vec{B}$ is constant over the whole area then the formula becomes

$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\phi$ = $\int {d\phi}$ = $\vec{B}$ .$\int{\vec dS}$ = $\vec{B}$ . $\vec{S}$.

This is how the expression $\phi$ = BS is derived.

Therefore you cannot obtain expression (2) (in the question) by differentiating $\phi$ = BS since it is applicable only in case of constant $\vec{B}$.

Comment: I understand, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first formula is used when B=const, the second is more general, sometimes dS=0 and you get d(phi)=dBS for example if you move a magnet to a coil, or by changes of B like in a transformer. I doubt "This formula is the same in almost all physics textbooks." it is only used if B=const.